# Pivot Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with columns of type varchar. how to pivot them.

My table initially looks like

```
Product Id Name                     Value

P1      Version Type          v1

P1      License Type                POS

P1      Product Description       This is P1
```

I want to transpose this to produce the following

```
Product Id    Version Type  License Type   Product Description

P1          v1          POS     This is P1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.ProductId, t2.VersionType, t3.LicenceType, t4.ProductDescription
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 on t1.ProductId = t2.ProductId
                  AND t2.Name = 'Version Type'
LEFT JOIN table t3 on t1.ProductId = t3.ProductId
                  AND t3.Name = 'License Type'
LEFT JOIN table t4 on t1.ProductId = t4.ProductId
                  AND t4.Name = 'Product Description'
WHERE t1.ProductId = ?
```

Comment: Instead of `FROM table t1`, it's better to have: `FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ProductId FROM table) t1`, if we want to have all products in the pivot query.

Comment: I assumed that it's a key (unique). If it's not, your `DISTINCT` is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any below mention way to get the desired result.

```
Select ProductID,
    Min(Case Name When 'Version Type' Then Value End) [Version Type],
    Min(Case Name When 'License Type' Then Value End) [License Type],
    Min(Case Name When 'Product Description' Then Value End) [Product Description]
From <TABLE NAME>
Group By ProductID
```

or using `Pivot` query

```
select * from (select ProductID, name, value from <TABLENAME>) as tbl
Pivot
(
 max(value)
 for name in ([Version Type], [License Type], [Product Description])
) as p
```